# What is the best way to get from Tirana (Albania) to Dubrovnik (Croatia)?

Tags: transportation, croatia, albania, dubrovnik, tirana

I have recently traveled from Tirana to Dubrovnik (airport) in a rather 'would not like to do it again' way that included more then a whole day of buses walking and hitch-hiking so i am curious to find out what is the best budget way to do this route in one day.

Answer (score 1):

### By bus

- Bus from Dubrovnik to Budva (3 hours)
- Bus from Budva to Ulcinj (1.5
  hour)
- Bus from Ulchinj to Tirana (3.5 hours)

### By Ferry

- From Dubrovnik to Bari
- From Bari to Durres
- Bus from Durres to Tirana

Or

Just rent a car

Comment: I was actually asking for the other way round. Still, do you have any more information regarding this bus from Tirana do Ulcinj? The single online reference i found for is through http://www.balkanviator.com/en/bus-timetables/tirana-alb/ulcinj-mne/  and since i have not heard of any such option while in Tirana i am a bit skeptical about it. Furthemore 14:00 departure makes it pretty much impossible to reach Dubrovnik the same day so I presume the suggested way is not feasible. Thanks for trying though. Also do you perhaps have any schedule link regarding this ferry option?

Comment: I only now noticed properly your ferry idea(thought it was Bar at first). I must say it is a very optimistic and utterly non budget and lengthy idea.  44 euros deck ticket for an night ferry to Bari, then another 50 for a 'every second day' evening ferry to Dubrovnik is hardly sensible.